# jQuery firing multiple times

Tags: jquery, html

I have buttons that are added dynamically and I need to have an event listener on them.

If I target them in a normal way it will not work so I found this solution:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click', "[data-name='add']", function(){
    var lastP = $('p:last');
    lastP.clone().insertAfter(lastP)
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Hello</p>
<button data-name="add">Click</button>
```

However, with this solution it works fine on the first load or on refresh. If I navigate to another page and go back to this, it adds the p tag multiple times (twice on the second load, three on third etc.). I tried to remove `$(document).ready(function() {` but it didn't change anything.

How can I prevent it and make it add the element only once?

Comment: Where are you adding the code?

Comment: At the end of my .html partial, which is rendered above the footer (if I understood your question correctly).

Answer (score 1):

I would just use [`Event.preventDefault`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) and [`Event.stopPropagation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) to make sure it is not called multiple times.

EDIT: OP commented below that `Event.stopImmediatePropagation()` solved his issue!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click', "[data-name='add']", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    var lastP = $('p:last');
    lastP.clone().insertAfter(lastP)
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Hello</p>
<button data-name="add">Click</button>
```

Comment: Seems like e.stopImmediatePropagation() solved the problem!

Answer (score 0):

`stopImmediatePropagation` solved the issue:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click', "[data-name='add']", function(e){
    e.stopImmediatePropagation()
    var lastP = $('p:last');
    lastP.clone().insertAfter(lastP)
  })
})
```